# IME Widget to enter 한글 input in editor?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed other exchange sites have special input widgets like:

- Code snippet editor on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- Balsamiq mockups on [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com)
- Latex/Math editor [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Would it make sense to embed a Korean IME right into the site? I thought of this idea as I was writing an [answer to: Are there any online tools available for entering Korean text?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/191/103) I'm not sure if it's possible to license Google's input tools, but I'm sure there are other solutions, too.

Comment: When you install a Korean language keyboard in your operating system, it should come with an IME.

Comment: I wouldnt mind giving some development help to add one if needed, but I didnt really see any way to add it